# Tableview won't load array correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

My tableView is acting really strange and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. So I have two problems. One problem is that my tableView is displaying a cell with the wrong child. This child is already been displayed and therefore the tableView is displaying one child with all of its data not. This wrong cell is the same as first cell of the tableView. I am not sure why the tableView does this. I fetch all the data in a Firebase child, but somehow the tableView will load the first child that it has already showed and won't show the actual child. That was my first problem.

Second problem is that my tableView won't reload the page after it has been reloaded. The cells wont update even when I cleared my array, insert new data and reload my tableView.

My code:

```
    var Soort_Bier = "" //Depends on the button clicked on the page before, but it is for example: "Alles" or "Kratten"
    var bier_model: [BierModel] = []

    func FetchFirebase () {
        self.bier_model.removeAll()
        Database.database().reference().child("Bier").child("\(Soort_Bier)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let value = snap.value as? NSDictionary
                        let key = snap.key
                        let bier = BierModel.transformbier(dict: postDict, key: key)
                        let Logo_Image = value?["Logo_Image"] as? String ?? ""
                        if Logo_Image != "" {
                             self.bier_model.insert(bier, at: 0)
                             self.tableView.reloadData()
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.Indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    func Korting() {
        self.bier_model.removeAll()
        Database.database().reference().child("Bier").child("\(Soort_Bier)").queryOrdered(byChild: "Item1Int").queryStarting(atValue: 0).queryEnding(atValue: 10000).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let value = snap.value as? NSDictionary
                        let key = snap.key
                        let bier = BierModel.transformbier(dict: postDict, key: key)
                        let Logo_Image = value?["Logo_Image"] as? String ?? "" 
                         if Logo_Image != "" {
                             self.bier_model.insert(bier, at: 0)
                             self.tableView.reloadData()
                         }  
                    }
                }
            }
            for test in self.bier_model {
                print("Title: \(test.Title!), Korting: \(test.Item_1!)")
            }
            self.Indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.2,
            delay: 0.0005 * Double(indexPath.row),
            animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
        })
    } 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return bier_model.count
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Bier_Cell", for: indexPath) as! Bier_TableViewCell

            let bier = bier_model[indexPath.row]
            cell.bier = bier

            return cell
        }
```

What it printed when called `Korting`:

```
Title: Jopen Mooie Nel, Korting: €1,80 korting (10%)
Title: Sol, Korting: €1,60 korting (20%)
Title: Affligem Blond, Korting: €1,60 korting (20%)
Title: Brand Up, Korting: €1,05 korting (15%)
Title: Desperados, Korting: €0,85 korting (10%)
Title: Heineken Pilsener, Korting: €0,60 korting (10%)
```

Okay, so let me explain my code. When the page loads for the first time the function `FetchFirebase` will be called. After that, when pressed on a button, the function `Korting` will be called. This should update the tableView and put the array in a different order. When I print the array in both functions, the array has no extra data. It just has the data init from Firebase. Also if the function `Korting` is called and I print the array everything seems to be in the correct order. But somehow the data will not show correctly in the tableView.

My Firebase Structure:

```
{
  "Bier" : {
    "Alles" : {
      "-LlCMf3Mrbv0xPjQ9guH" : {
        "Beschrijving" : "Krat 24x0,30",
        "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "",
        "Footer_item" : "t/m zaterdag 3 augustus",
        "Item1Int" : 650,
        "Item2Int" : 146,
        "Item_1" : "€6,50 korting (38%)",
        "Item_2" : "€1,46 per liter",
        "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/23026-grolsch%20krat%20normale%20flesjes%2030%20cl.png",
        "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/17335-agrimarkt.gif",
        "Title" : "Grolsch Premium Pilsener",
        "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/grolsch-premium-pilsener",
        "Van_prijs" : "€16,99",
        "Van_prijs_int" : 1699,
        "Voor_prijs" : "€10,49",
        "voorPrijs" : 1049
      },//With some more data
     },
     "Torpen" : {
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439Q" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 160,
    "Item2Int" : 320,
    "Item_1" : "€1,60 korting (20%)",
    "Item_2" : "€3,20 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/45314-2%20liter%20torp%20Affligem%20blond.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Affligem Blond",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/affligem-blond",
    "Van_prijs" : "€7,99",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 799,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€6,39",
    "voorPrijs" : 639
  },
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439R" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 105,
    "Item2Int" : 297,
    "Item_1" : "€1,05 korting (15%)",
    "Item_2" : "€2,97 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/45319-2%20liter%20torp%20Brand%20up.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Brand Up",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/brand-up",
    "Van_prijs" : "€6,99",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 699,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€5,94",
    "voorPrijs" : 594
  },
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439S" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 180,
    "Item2Int" : 810,
    "Item_1" : "€1,80 korting (10%)",
    "Item_2" : "€8,10 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/58674-jopen%20mooie%20nel%20torp.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Jopen Mooie Nel",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/jopen-mooie-nel",
    "Van_prijs" : "€17,99",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 1799,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€16,19",
    "voorPrijs" : 1619
  },
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439T" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 85,
    "Item2Int" : 382,
    "Item_1" : "€0,85 korting (10%)",
    "Item_2" : "€3,82 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/45329-2%20liter%20torp%20Desperados%20Tequila.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Desperados",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/desperados",
    "Van_prijs" : "€8,49",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 849,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€7,64",
    "voorPrijs" : 764
  },
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439U" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 160,
    "Item2Int" : 320,
    "Item_1" : "€1,60 korting (20%)",
    "Item_2" : "€3,20 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/49319-Sol%20Torp%20van%202%20liter.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Sol",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/sol",
    "Van_prijs" : "€7,99",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 799,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€6,39",
    "voorPrijs" : 639
  },
  "-LlCMf3Tcrt5l4si439V" : {
    "Beschrijving" : "Torp 2L",
    "Bestel_Online_link_url" : "Bestel online",
    "Footer_item" : "t/m zondag 4 augustus",
    "Item1Int" : 60,
    "Item2Int" : 270,
    "Item_1" : "€0,60 korting (10%)",
    "Item_2" : "€2,70 per liter",
    "Item_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/soort/45309-2%20liter%20torp%20Heineken.png",
    "Logo_Image" : "https://www.biernet.nl/images/winkel/54870-Beerwulf%20logo%20wolf.jpg",
    "Title" : "Heineken Pilsener",
    "Url" : "https://www.biernet.nl/bier/merken/heineken-pilsener",
    "Van_prijs" : "€5,99",
    "Van_prijs_int" : 599,
    "Voor_prijs" : "€5,39",
    "voorPrijs" : 539
  }
}
}
```

Class:

```
class BierModel {
    var Logo_Image: String?
    var Van_prijs: String?
    var Url: String?
    var Voor_prijs: String?
    var Beschrijving: String?
    var Item_Image: String?
    var Title: String?
    var Bestel_Online_link: String?
    var Footer_item: String?
    var Item_1: String?
    var Item1Int: Int?
    var Item_2: String?
    var Item2Int: Int?
    var Voor_prijs_int: Int?
    var Van_prijs_Int: Int?
}

extension BierModel {
    static func transformbier(dict: [String: Any], key: String) -> BierModel {
        let bier = BierModel()
        bier.Logo_Image = dict["Logo_Image"] as? String
        bier.Van_prijs = dict["Van_prijs"] as? String
        bier.Voor_prijs = dict["Voor_prijs"] as? String
        bier.Beschrijving = dict["Beschrijving"] as? String
        bier.Item_Image = dict["Item_Image"] as? String
        bier.Title = dict["Title"] as? String
        bier.Bestel_Online_link = dict["Bestel_Online_link_url"] as? String
        bier.Footer_item = dict["Footer_item"] as? String
        bier.Item_1 = dict["Item_1"] as? String
        bier.Item1Int = dict["Item1Int"] as? Int
        bier.Item_2 = dict["Item_2"] as? String
        bier.Item2Int = dict["Item2Int"] as? Int
        bier.Voor_prijs_int = dict["voorPrijs"] as? Int
        bier.Van_prijs_Int = dict["Van_prijs_Int"] as? Int
        bier.Url = dict["Url"] as? String
        return bier
    }
}
```

This is a video of what my error looks like on my iPhone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnKGdm0mi_M

This is all strange to me and I am trying to fix this problem for a few days now. Please somebody help me!

Comment: does your issue resolved?

Comment: @SharadPaghadal It doesn't seem to fix my problem. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The code is self explaining the issue, You are doing UI kind of work in background thread. `tableview.realoadData()` must get called in main thread.

As you can see firebase method is giving you data in callback - it means not in main thread, and tableview.reloadData() is kind of UI stuff.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableview.reloadData()    
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was for a few hours away from keyboard, but I doesn't seem to fix my problem. Do you have other suggestions?